# Inserting an initial user into my database on bash deployment

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, debian

I'm trying to create an initial user in my postgresql database on deployment. Apparently I need to generate a `pbkdf2:sha1` key of the password that I want for the user.

For example, say I wanted to add an admin account with username "admin" and password "admin" I would need to hash the password "admin" before inserting it into the table I believe.

Can anyone tell me how I might do this in bash, for example, I tried something along these lines but it didn't seem to work:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "$ADMIN_PASSWORD"
```

EDIT: This is a password for **postgres** database, that's why it needs to be hashed before it can be inserted. I want to achieve this hashing in bash and not python.

Comment: Problem unclear. Who receive the submitted data and read the data in DB in order to have a verify it's a good or bad login?

Comment: ```python -c "from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash; print generate_password_hash("password")" ``` I'm using python to hash the password but I want to do it in bash

Comment: Then why not make this line of python to be a script file and run it in bash?

Comment: It seems bash is able to complete the task, so I am hoping to be able to achieve the same result in bash

Comment: I don't see the difference between using `openssl` or using `python` :) Besides, the `generate_password_hash` in `werkzeug` is specific for itself use (e.g. How many iterations) I think. So If you want to generate passwd for `werkzeug`, you should use the python code.

Comment: The password isn't for werkzeug, it's just a way of doing the hash. This can be achieved with openssl I simply do not want to be inserting python when it can be handled by bash

Comment: the point of @mitnk is, that `openssl` is **not bash**, it is just another application you start from your shell; if you are fine with starting application *A* (e.g. `openssl`) then why do you refuse to start application *B* (your python script)? `bash` itself has no (sane) way to generate the hash, you *must* resort to an "external" program.

Comment: @umläute There are three problems with the python approach employed by @Jimmy . First, python interpreter takes time to start. Try `bash -c 'time echo -n admin | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac'` and `bash -c "time python -c 'import hashlib; print(hashlib.sha1(\"admin\").hexdigest())'"`, the latter takes about five times as long. Secondly, it's pretty stupid (and amusing) to call another interpreter from an interpreter. I only do that when it's absolutely necessary, and even then it's a shame. Thirdly, what the heck is `werkzeug.security`? The standard library has `hashlib` for hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input should be passed through stdin. Do this:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
echo -n "${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac
```

And you will get output

```
d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997
```

on stdout. If you'd rather save it to a variable to be referenced later, do

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
SHA1SUM=$(echo "${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac)
```

And later refer to the hash as `${SHA1SUM}`.

Note: curly braces in `${ADMIN_PASSWORD}` and `${SHA1SUM}` are optional.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a one-off task, the hash value will never change - it's a constant, so code it that way:

discover what hash your applicatiin would create for the "admin" user with a password of "admin", and hard-code it into your bash script.

Comment: Thank you for the input. In this case, the password will be generated randomly as part of the script and then needs hashing, so whilst your idea is a good one, I do need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you have PostgreSQL generate the hash for you? The functions `crypt()` and `gen_salt()` come with some examples, see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not trying to create a user for postgres though, im trying to insert an inital database entry into my database to be used by my application for a front-end login.

Comment: Ah, I see. But this is what you asked: "I'm trying to create an initial user in my postgresql database on deployment". You may want to add "for my application" or something similar, even though the two others seem to have understood you right away. What kind of software (PHP, Python,...) does your web application use?

Comment: @Jimmy: Answer edited with link to crypt()/gen_salt() examples. I don't know how your app does the authentication, but that is how PostgreSQL supports both auth. and pw change.